# Creating a second rendering context for a window

Tags: multithreading, opengl, glfw

I have an OpenGL window opened using glfw under linux and I am trying to use OpenGL in a two threads.
I understood from reading around the web that I am supposed to open a second rendering context with the same window. Only one of the threads will be actually used for rendering, while the other will be used to exchange data through PBOs.

The question is how can I get the needed params to call `glxCreateContext()` for the window I opened using glfw?

EDIT: I ended creating 2 rendering contexts, with shared lists. which is probably a better idea.